# Jupyter notebook move rectangle over (imshow) plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, data-visualization

I plot a nd-array, and display a rectangle in a fixed point. However I want to be able to move the rectangle (when I move the mouse), and display something (according to the coordinates of the mouse / Rectangle). Is there a way to implement such a thing in Jupyter notebook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[mplcursors](https://mplcursors.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) can show interactive annotations together with extra elements. In the following demo, the annotation displays the value of the current cell together with the mean of the surrounding cells. A rectangle indicates the selected region.

```py
%matplotlib notebook
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
import mplcursors

def show_rect(sel):
    x, y = sel.target
    i, j = sel.target.index
    i0 = i if i == 0 else i - 1
    i1 = i if i == M.shape[0] - 1 else i + 1
    j0 = j if j == 0 else j - 1
    j1 = j if j == M.shape[1] - 1 else j + 1
    annotation_text = f'{i},{j}: {M[sel.target.index]}\nRegion mean: {M[i0:i1 + 1, j0:j1 + 1].mean():.2f}'
    sel.annotation.set_text(annotation_text)
    rect = Rectangle((j0 - 0.5, i0 - 0.5), j1 - j0 + 1, i1 - i0 + 1,
                     edgecolor='lime', linewidth=3, facecolor='none', clip_on=False)
    ax.add_artist(rect)
    sel.extras.append(rect)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9, 3))
M = np.random.randint(1, 101, size=(8, 12))
img = ax.imshow(M, cmap='coolwarm', vmin=0, vmax=100, aspect='auto')
plt.colorbar(img, ax=ax)

cursor = mplcursors.cursor(img, hover=True)
cursor.connect('add', show_rect)
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: This implementation worked before, but when I try it now, the text appears to be at the left corner, and the arrow pointing to the center does not move (it keeps adding more arrows as I move the mouse instead of moving the original one). Do you know what might causes it? (I didn't change the code). thanks!

Comment: Are you running in the same environment? With the latest matplotlib version? Maybe some function is setting `%matplotlib notebook` to something else?

Comment: I've upgraded the matplotlib version and it works, thanks!